# Are multiple weak references to the same object cleared in groups?

Tags: java, weak-references

If I have multiple weak references pointing at the same object, and no strong references are around. Can I be sure both weak references are intact when one of them returns the object?

Comment: They will either all be set or cleared together.  However, if you are relying on this fact I would reconsider your design because from one instruction to the next this can change.

Comment: @Peter_Lawrey I'm totally sure they'll be deleted all together, althought it may appear logical. Anyway, relying upon in functional code would be a total nightmare.

Comment: I'm mostly asking this from a theoretical point of view. I want to know if it's safe to use multiple weak references to the same object in my design. I'm considering to use task objects, and once a task is done I drop all strong references. However, if a done task is retrieved at  a later point, I need to be sure my model is still in a consistent state so I can skip additional checking.

Comment: its safe and actually is common to use multiple weakrefs pointing to same obj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WeakReference wr1 = new WeakReference(objX);
...//somewhere else
WeakReference wr2 = new WeakReference(objX);
```

Now:

1. If at a moment wr1.get() returns non-null, then wr2.get() will return non-null too.
2. But wr1 and wr2 object themselves are gc-ed independently, their gs-paths are independent of each other and most importantly independent of objX.

Comment: At point 2, you mean if I store the weak references in a weak reference them self? Because I do not see why wr1 and wr2 would be gc'ed while I can still reach them otherwise.

Comment: what i meant was is that gcing of wr1 and wr2 is independent of gcing of objX

Comment: Yeah i got it. Something to keep in mind when working with weak references.

Comment: This answer has no reference to the JVM spec, or an implementation of a JVM or any sort of evidence that this is indeed true.